# Why is the title attribute not attainable?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Trying to learn basic webscraping with exercises but ran into a problem....

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals")
base_content = base_url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(base_content, features='html5lib')
links = soup.find_all('a')
for a in links:
    if a.text == str(a.attrs["title"]):
        print(a.text)
```

This always result in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/prana/capcitywiki.py", line 9, in <module>
    if a.text == str(a.attrs["title"]):
KeyError: 'title'
```

any help??

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of anchors on the page that don't have `title` attributes. E.g. `<a id="top"></a>` and `<a class="mw-jump-link" href="#mw-head">Jump to navigation</a>`.

You can use a selector that only finds anchors with titles.

```
links = soup.select('a[title]')
```